# How to plot odds ratio/risk ratio and 95% CI from multiple models in R

Tags: r, glm

I have estimates from three negative binomial regression models. I'd like to only plot the exponential estimates (odds ratio) of the exposure variable from all three models into one plot (something like forest plot or dot whisker). I only did this through `dwplot` and it's not exponential.
[image]

I'm wondering if there is any package or codes I can use to produce the similar plot but in exponential form? Thank you!

Here is the data I used to generate the dot-whisker plot

```
df <- structure(list(term = c("(Intercept)", "class3b1", "class3b3", 
"(Intercept)", "class3b1", "class3b3", "(Intercept)", "class3b1", 
"class3b3"), estimate = c(`(Intercept)` = 0.733889003356554, 
class3b1 = 0.199515823440595, class3b3 = 0.131388675627862, `(Intercept)` = 1.79754882887546, 
class3b1 = 0.36102170683221, class3b3 = 0.139655070741534, `(Intercept)` = 1.60943791243411, 
class3b1 = 0.362583380624898, class3b3 = 0.145763961060158), 
    std.error = c(`(Intercept)` = 0.754245712715592, class3b1 = 0.241859302693499, 
    class3b3 = 0.168773219758597, `(Intercept)` = 0.276527974096511, 
    class3b1 = 0.245193969634718, class3b3 = 0.17297021770553, 
    `(Intercept)` = 0.0857726461773874, class3b1 = 0.241888740986895, 
    class3b3 = 0.170656445866946), statistic = c(`(Intercept)` = 0.973010507032588, 
    class3b1 = 0.824925157803153, class3b3 = 0.778492439830158, 
    `(Intercept)` = 6.50042309371601, class3b1 = 1.472392275267, 
    class3b3 = 0.807393738610467, `(Intercept)` = 18.7639997617144, 
    class3b1 = 1.49896757966317, class3b3 = 0.854136861456757
    ), p.value = c(`(Intercept)` = 0.330548080081182, class3b1 = 0.409414082399228, 
    class3b3 = 0.436278761845928, `(Intercept)` = 8.00944274910155e-11, 
    class3b1 = 0.140914977949294, class3b3 = 0.419439673184529, 
    `(Intercept)` = 1.48771581352615e-78, class3b1 = 0.133882042874179, 
    class3b3 = 0.393029161859892), model = c("Adjusted for family and individual level features", 
    "Adjusted for family and individual level features", "Adjusted for family and individual level features", 
    "Adjusted for family level features", "Adjusted for family level features", 
    "Adjusted for family level features", "Univariate model", 
    "Univariate model", "Univariate model")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: There is an issue with your data. I suspect we miss the first line?

Comment: @TarJae Yes sorry I just notice this. Thank you! I correct the code.